# Get full ID for specific calendar event using only Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I would like to generate an html link to a public event so someone can click it and be taken directly to the event in google calendar.

Here's an example: [link to a specific public calendar event](https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=Z3FrNWoyaWhtOGM5MmpjcDM5bjkxZGczcnNfMjAxMzExMjZUMTAwMDAwWiA5Nm1wdTg4djJkM29ucWtwNnBoOTg2NXAxY0Bn&ctz=Asia/Taipei).

I know the format is as follows

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid={event-id}&ctz={timezone}
```

The question was asked [here previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067471/get-eventid-for-google-calendar-event), but the answer requires turning on advanced services and using the calendar api which seems like overkill to retrieve the full event id.

Is there really no way to get the full id using just apps script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. Im new to development so there may be a better way to write this.

```
function createEvent(){
var stringId = 'insertYourCalId';
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(stringId);
var event = calendarId.createEvent(title, eventStart, eventEnd);
var eventId = event.getId().split("@")[0].toString();
var eventLink = Calendar.Events.get(stringId, eventId).htmlLink;
}
```